# Active Sync Login Time Restriction

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, exchange-2003, activesync

Is there any other location restricting a user from accessing their emails from their phone using active sync, besides on a domain controller ->active directory->user properties - > account -> logon hours. The user's logon hours are allowed all the time.

To add to the mystery the user is an admin on the domain.(He seems not to be able to get emails from 7:00pm to 8:00pm)

Its a Windows 2003 Server environment.
Thanks for any help ahead of time.

Comment: Knowing what version of Exchange is in use would be helpful.

Comment: We have Exchange 2003

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no built-in functionality to do what you're describing other than logon hours. Since you've already checked that I'd say that you've got some kind of malfunction occurring.

The IIS logs on the ActiveSync server should probably be your first stop. If you can get a good report from a user of an exact time / date of the problem you should be able to search the IIS logs to find out what type of error IIS is returning to the client (or if the client is even checking-in with the server computer).